# Issue in PlayFramework 2.7.0, sbt-play-ebean 5.0.1 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65791

Tags: scala, sbt, play-framework-2.7

I'm using following plugins & Versions

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
sbt.version=1.2.7
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "5.0.1")
```

I'm getting following stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65791
[error]     at scala.tools.asm.ClassWriter.findItemByIndex(ClassWriter.java:1755)
[error]     at scala.tools.asm.MethodWriter.getSize(MethodWriter.java:2045)
[error]     at scala.tools.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(ClassWriter.java:827)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JBuilder.writeIfNotTooBig(GenASM.scala:529)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JPlainBuilder.genClass(GenASM.scala:1343)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase.emitFor$1(GenASM.scala:197)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase.run(GenASM.scala:203)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1500)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1487)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1482)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1580)
[error]     at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:130)...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
sbt.version=1.2.7
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "5.0.1")
```

`sbt-play-ebean 5.0.1` has Scala Version `2.13.0-M5`,`2.12`, and `2.11` supported.
So maybe you can try to use `Java 8 Version` because `java 9 and up` has a lot of incompatibilities.

Hope it helps.